# Vuejs Ternary Operator / Conditional Not Working in v-bind-style

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, conditional-statements, ternary-operator

I'm getting some weird behavior trying to implement a conditional for the style of items in Vuejs.

I have seen S.O. posts on how to implement a ternary, via both an interpolated string or a computed style object. I've tried both but neither works properly.

Given this div:

```
<div 
    :class="{'radar__container':true,'inactive':inactive}"
    :style= "[inactive ? {getStyleRadarContainerInactive} : {getStyleRadarContainer}]"
  >
```

I would implement this style:

```
computed: {
    getStyleRadarContainer: function(){

        let styleRadarContainer = {
            left: this.radarItem.posX*100 + '%', 
            top: this.radarItem.posY*100 + '%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%) scale(' + this.radarItem.scale + ')',
            opacity: this.radarItem.opacity,
        }

        return styleRadarContainer;
    },
    getStyleRadarContainerInactive: function(){

        let styleRadarContainerInactive= {
            left: this.radarItem.posX*100 + '%', 
            top: this.radarItem.posY*100 + '%',
            transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0)',
            opacity: this.radarItem.opacity,
        }

        return styleRadarContainerInactive;
    },
  }
```

This should make each of these items scale down (because of the scale(0) in opacity property),but instead the style attribute doesn't render at all. I also tried an inline ternary on the style prop (since that scale is the only thing that changes between the two properties:

```
transform: 'translate(-50%,-50%) ' + inactive ? 'scale(' + radarItem.scale + ')' : 'scale(0)',
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style binding expects an object. By wrapping the ternary in square brackets, you're passing in an array containing an object, which is unnecessary. Also, you're wrapping the returned object on either side of the ternary in brackets, which is nesting them further. Removing those brackets will let the returned object can be handled in correctly:

```
<div 
    :class="{'radar__container':true,'inactive':inactive}"
    :style= "inactive ? getStyleRadarContainerInactive : getStyleRadarContainer"
  >
```

As a side note, if you add a variable containing an object to another object without specifying property name, the variable name is used as a property name.

```js
var myObject = {
  property: 'value'
};

$('#output').html(JSON.stringify({myObject}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use condition in V-bind:style

```
v-bind:style= "[condition ? {style_A} : {style_B}]"
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Answer (score 1):

There should work if you use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) like this:

```
:style= "[inactive ? {...getStyleRadarContainerInactive} : {...getStyleRadarContainer}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution did not work because you produced double curly brackets

```
  :style="[{ obj: { styleObject }}]" // This won't work
```

You can either have an array containing styleObjects or only a styleObject.

E.g.

```
  :style="[ { color: 'blue' } ]"
  :style="{ color: 'blue' }"
```

Comment: Interesting, I did not know it would merge them if you supply an array of objects... thanks for that. that could be useful at some point :) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yup they merge with properties of objects to the right overriding those on the left